# On determinants computation

Tags: matrices, determinant

How can be proved this identity between determinants?
$$\left|\begin{array}{cccc}
1&a&c&ac\\
1&b&c&bc\\
1&a&d&ad\\
1&b&d&bd
\end{array}\right|=\left|
\begin{array}{cc}
1&a\\
1&b
\end{array}
\right|^2\left|\begin{array}{cc}
1&c\\
1&d\end{array}\right|^2$$

Comment: Show us some work of your try to solve it.

Comment: You can always expand the right hand side and use the definition of the determinant of a $4\times 4$ for the left hand side. But may be you're looking for something more clever...

Comment: One way is to compute the LHS and RHS and find they are the same. It's not that hard, so where are you struggling?

Comment: @Sudarsan well, my only work has been a concrete computation of the two sides of the equation (which is my personal guess, but it seems correct), i'm looking for a general method for solving this, i note that the last column is the product of the previous two...

Comment: @bateman Look at the Kronecker-product. That's much more to what you'll be looking for. I wrote it as a Hint answer. Maybe I'll add details if you show some initiative.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**
Take a loot at the Kronecker-Product. With the RHS noted as $|A|^2 |B|^2$ you have
$$\text{LHS} = B \otimes A$$